# NodeJS can't find bower_components but can find node_modules on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, bower

I'm new with node on windows and trying to run a simple hello world http server using `express`.

When I install `express` via the `npm` everything works ok.

I wanted to start working with `bower` as well so I've uninstalled the `npm` `express` package and re-installed it via `bower`.

I have **no** problems with `bower` or `npm`. The packages are installed and I can see the sources.

They are both installed in the same level (e.g. the npm packages and the bower packages are two different sibling directories), but it seems to me that the nodejs runtime **doesn't** understand that the `bower_components` directory is a potential directory for packages (while it **does** understand that the `node_modules` is).

Is there anyway I can define an additional directory path for the runtime to find packages in places other than the `node_modules` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Bower is a front-end dependency manager, and thus can not manage packages for nodejs.

The equivalent to this for the server side and NodeJS is npm. Consider using npm packages instead with something like webpack or browserify in order to serve assets from your npm packages to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Bower in your system and install all bower dependencies in app.
Like `npm install -g bower`
and install  dependencies `bower install <package>`